# how to Style forms next to each other with Ruby

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, styling

i'm trying to style a form to have the following layout:

```
[DateBegin]     [DateEnd]
.Input field.  .Input field.
```

Is this possible with RoR? If so how do I do it, I tried with  but clearly that didn't work, do I have to style it with divs? I'm using bootstrap, if there is a good bootstrap solution I'd like to know aswell, help/ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is sample view for your requested format, field are date_begin and date_end

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :date_begin,"Label for Date begin" %>
       <%= f.text_field :date_begin, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :date_end,"label for date end" %>
       <%= f.text_field :date_end, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```